# Oh snap Jquery Plugin - Notification Not Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the following plugin for alerts on my page: http://justindomingue.github.io/ohSnap/

I have the plugin working within all of my JS functions.

What is not happening though is the position. The alerts are supposed to be in the bottom right corner of the page, and stack on top of each other if there are multiple. They do stack. They are in the bottom right corner, BUT let's say the user scrolls down my page to submit a form. The notification DOES NOT appear in the new bottom right corner, but appears in the original position before the page was scrolled.

The CSS for the alerts position is:

```
.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eed3d7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 21px;
  /* Each alert has its own width */
  float: right; 
  clear: right;
}
```

I tried changing position to fixed, but got the same exact result.

I'm hoping someone here has used this plugin before and experienced the same results with solution.

UPDATE WITH SOLUTION

It turns out that the plugin page is lacking a piece of code used in the demo page source. After using the missing piece it works fine now.

Comment: Just a side note. I'd prefix your `.alert` class because it's very generic and most likely going to appear on many different websites, or wherever your plugin is used. Maybe prefix all of your classes with ohsnap. For example `ohsnap-alert`

Comment: Good thinking. I actually didn't notice the class name because I copied and pasted the CSS from the original site lol I think I'll get on that now. Thanks :)

Comment: @gautsch while you're right, it's not jesse's plugin. They are just using it.

Comment: He has a point that it would be better to edit it though, at least to a non-generic class.

Comment: @JesseElser that's why i prefaced with saying they were right

Comment: Guys I figured it out lol it turns out that the code given for the plugin tutorial is missing a piece that positions it entirely lol I believe I am going to e-mail them so they can update their demo page.